# How to get RFID tag from ACS122U NFC

Tags: android, nfc, acr122

I am working on ACS122U NFC which reads tag's RFID. From ACS  http://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/3/acr122u-usb-nfc-reader/ I got the development kit which will only connect to the reader and gives the state when a tag is placed on the NFC reader. But I need to get the ID (UID, serial number) of a tag for further implementation. How can I get the ID of a tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get UID you have to send an APDu command.

Please download the datasheet given at link :
[acr-122u datasheet](http://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/419/API-ACR122U-2.03.pdf)

In that, check

> 4.1 Get Data

below this,
Get UID APDU format,

> FF CA 00 00 00

**UPDATE :**

Follow the steps:

1. APDU command : 0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
2. Send APDU using send/transmit command(according to given SDK of the reader)
3. Get response
4. convert response(which is in `byte` or `unsigned char`) to `char`
5. Print reponse

Comment: Thankyou for the response @Jyo. Is this what you are talking about.byte[] command = { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xCA, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 };
 byte[] response = new byte[300];
 int responseLength;
 responseLength = reader.transmit(slotNum, command, command.length, response,response.length);
 System.out.println(new String(response));

Comment: Yeah, your command is right, send it according to transmit command given in the SDK of your reader.To print response, convert response from byte->char.

Comment: how can you create reader object instance ?

Comment: Creating an object of the reader is depend on the given SDK  for the reader, as SDK is developed by reader vendor, syntax may vary accordingly.